# ASP.NET MVC deploy to iis not auto compile

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, compiled

I have an ASP.NET(Framework4.6.1) MVC project,
If I deploy to IIS is the entire project,It can work.
But If I only change some .cs or .cshtml files,iis won't recompile

I want to ask:
Can I just change some of the .cs or .cshtml files to allow iis to be recompiled instead of uploading the entire project each time?

My system information

1. ASP.NET(Framework4.6.1) MVC project
2. EntityFramework,Version=6.0.0.0
3. IIS 7.5 integration

web.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="SessionTimeout" value="6000" />

      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="102400" />
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>

      </system.web>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
          <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>

      </system.webServer>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.cs` - You could just upload the DLL file, if the changes are very minimal.

`.cshtml` - You just copy and replace the individual file in IIS assuming you don't modify the corresponding controllers.

You might want to look at web deploy which deploys only the necessary files instead of entire application.

> Can I just change some of the .cs or .cshtml files to allow iis to be
>   recompiled instead of uploading the entire project each time?

If you open the `web.config` file in notepad and just click `File > Save` or just copy and replace the same `web.config` file, then IIS will recompile the application.

Note: Replacing `.cshtml` file doesn't require the application to be recompiled.

Comment: Thank you!However, I did not compile it into a .dll file,Can I just update .cs and reopen IIS or use IIS to help me recompile?

Comment: Normally, we won't see `.cs` file inside the published application. Are you trying to copy the entire source code to IIS folder? How did you publish your MVC application?

Comment: It is *not* how we deploy ASP.NET application. Right click on web  project and select `Publish...` Then choose either `IIS, FTP, and Web Deploy` or `Folder`. If you chose `Folder`, then you copy the compiled code to IIS.

Comment: @junyu Could you able to deploy the application or do you still have the issue?